# How to exclude fields from being copied

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Jooq offers a [from()](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Record.html#from%28java.lang.Object%29) method that let's you copy a DTO into a record.

However I'd like to copy only some fields to prevent clients from updating read-only information.

Ideally I'd like to be able to write something like:

```java
myrecord.from( mybean, "name", "description", "someOtherField")
```

or

```java
myrecord.from( mybean, User.NAME, User.DESCRIPTION, User.SOME_OTHER_FIELD)
```

and only have the three fields copied.

Of course it can be done by e.g. manually calling getters/setters, but I'd expect that there is an easier way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With jOOQ 3.0, there was no lean solution to your problem, short of what you said: copy values manually.

In jOOQ 3.1 [[#2519]](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/2519), you are able to do any of these:

```java
// Referencing fields that might be contained in myrecord
myrecord.from(mybean, User.NAME, User.DESCRIPTION, User.SOME_OTHER_FIELD);

// Referencing field names that might be contained in myrecord
myrecord.from(mybean, "name", "description", "some_other_field");

// Referencing field indexes that might be contained in myrecord
myrecord.from(mybean, 3, 4, 7);
```

Comment: You might want to update your answer to reflect the fact that this is now implemented in 3.1

Comment: @JakubBochenski: Done. Note, you can provide edit suggestions yourself on Stack Overflow...